# LINQ set value if not null

Tags: linq, null, return-value

I have the following code:

```
model.Attendees.Single(p => p.Value == this.CurrentPerson.PersonId.ToString() && p.Disabled == false).Selected = true;
```

The person is disabled so it brings back a null reference when trying to set Selected to true.

Is there a LINQ way of handeling this or should I do an if not null then set value.. I've tried Single and SingleOrDefault

Comment: I assume your goal to update the database to set the attendee as selected? A few more details on what you're trying to do would help us answer. Honestly the best way IMHO is to `SingleOrDefault` without the `p.Disabled` condition. Then do a null check and disabled check and handle telling the user they are disabled.. otherwise set the variable.selected to true and save.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best is (as commented) to first get the item with SingleOrDefault

```
var item = model.Attendees.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Value == this.CurrentPerson.PersonId.ToString() && p.Disabled == false);
```

And then to check or the item is null and if not use the object like:

```
if(item != null)
{
    item.Selected = true;
}
```